# Encountering urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, json, urllib2, urllib

I've tried all ways listed in other questions to debug this code but not able to fix this. As I'm a beginner in python, I'm not able to change urllib2 method with requests. With requests, I'm encountering keyerror: 'id' doesn't exist. Please help at the earliest.

Python code:

```
import os
os.environ['http_proxy']=''
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
import mysql.connector
import datetime
from config import config
import requests

def connect_db():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    return connection


def create_post_url(graph_url, APP_ID, APP_SECRET): 
    #create authenticated post URL
    post_args = "/posts/?key=value&access_token=" + APP_ID + "|" + APP_SECRET
    post_url = graph_url + post_args

    return post_url

def render_to_json(graph_url):
    #render graph url call to JSON
    web_response = urllib2.Request(graph_url)
    response= urllib2.urlopen(web_response)
    readable_data= response.read()
    json_data = json.loads(readable_data)

    return json_data

def scrape_posts_by_date(graph_url, date, post_data, APP_ID, APP_SECRET):
    #render URL to JSON
    page_posts = render_to_json(graph_url)

    #extract next page
    next_page = page_posts["paging"]["next"]

    #grab all posts
    page_posts = page_posts["data"]

    #boolean to tell us when to stop collecting
    collecting = True

    #for each post capture data
    #for post in page_posts:
            #for each post capture data
    for post in page_posts:
        try:
            likes_count = get_likes_count(post["id"], APP_ID, APP_SECRET)
            current_post = [post["id"], post["message"],
                    post["created_time"], 
                                        post["shares"]["count"]]        

        except Exception:
            current_post = [ "error", "error", "error", "error"]

        if current_post[2] != "error":
            print date
            print current_post[3]
            #compare dates
            if date <= current_post[3]:
                post_data.append(current_post)

            elif date > current_post[2]:
                print "Done collecting"
                collecting = False
                break


    #If we still don't meet date requirements, run on next page         
    if collecting == True:
        scrape_posts_by_date(next_page, date, post_data, APP_ID, APP_SECRET)

    return post_data

def get_likes_count(post_id, APP_ID, APP_SECRET):
    #create Graph API Call
    graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" 
    likes_args = post_id + "/likes?summary=true&key=value&access_token" + APP_ID + "|" + APP_SECRET
    likes_url = graph_url + likes_args
    likes_json = render_to_json(likes_url)

    #pick out the likes count
    count_likes = likes_json["summary"]["total_count"]

    return count_likes

def create_comments_url(graph_url, post_id, APP_ID, APP_SECRET):
    #create Graph API Call
    comments_args = post_id + "/comments/?key=value&access_token=" + APP_ID + "|" + APP_SECRET
    comments_url = graph_url + comments_args

    return comments_url

def get_comments_data(comments_url, comment_data, post_id):
    #render URL to JSON
    comments = render_to_json(comments_url)["data"]

    #for each comment capture data
    for comment in comments:
        try:
            current_comments = [comment["id"], comment["message"], comment["like_count"],
                        comment["created_time"], post_id]
            print current_comments
            comment_data.append(current_comments)

        except Exception:
            current_comments = ["error", "error", "error", "error", "error"]


    #check if there is another page
    try:
        #extract next page
        next_page = comments["paging"]["next"]
    except Exception:
        next_page = None


    #if we have another page, recurse
    if next_page is not None:
        get_comments_data(next_page, comment_data, post_id)
    else:
        return comment_data

def main():
    #simple data pull App Secret and App ID
    APP_SECRET = "app_secret"
    APP_ID = "app_id"

    #to find go to page's FB page, at the end of URL find username
    #e.g. http://facebook.com/walmart, walmart is the username
    list_companies = ["walmart", "cisco", "pepsi", "facebook"]
    graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"

    #the time of last weeks crawl
    last_crawl = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)
    last_crawl = last_crawl.isoformat()

    #create db connection
    connection = connect_db()
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    #SQL statement for adding Facebook page data to database
    insert_info = ("INSERT INTO page_info "
                    "(fb_id, likes, talking_about, username)"
                    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")

    #SQL statement for adding post data             
    insert_posts = ("INSERT INTO post_info "
                    "(fb_post_id, message, likes_count, time_created, shares, page_id)"
                    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

    #SQL statement for adding comment data
    insert_comments = ("INSERT INTO comment_info "
                       "(comment_id, message, likes_count, time_created, post_id)"
                       "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

    for company in list_companies:
        #make graph api url with company username
        current_page = graph_url + company

        #open public page in facebook graph api
        json_fbpage = render_to_json(current_page)


        #gather our page level JSON Data
        page_data = [json_fbpage["id"], json_fbpage["likes"],
                     json_fbpage["talking_about_count"],
                     json_fbpage["username"]]
        print page_data

        #extract post data
        post_url = create_post_url(current_page, APP_ID, APP_SECRET)
        post_data = []
        post_data = scrape_posts_by_date(post_url, last_crawl, post_data)

        print post_data

        #insert the data we pulled into db
        cursor.execute(insert_info, page_data)

        #grab primary key
        last_key = cursor.lastrowid

        comment_data = []

        #loop through and insert data
        for post in post_data:
            post.append(last_key)
            cursor.execute(insert_posts, post)

            #capture post id of data just inserted
            post_key = cursor.lastrowid
            print post_key
            comment_url = create_comments_url(graph_url, post[0], APP_ID, APP_SECRET)
            comments = get_comments_data(comment_url, comment_data, post_key)

            #insert comments
            for comment in comments:
                cursor.execute(insert_comments, comment)

        #commit the data to the db
        connection.commit()

    connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 210, in <module>
    main()    
  File "script.py", line 164, in main
    json_fbpage = render_to_json(current_page)
  File "script.py", line 26, in render_to_json
    response= urllib2.urlopen(web_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error you get.

Comment: You have too much code in your question.  Try to pair down to what the problem is.  And as @IanAuld said, copy and paste your full traceback so that we can help.  Requests is really better than urllib, but use what you wish

Comment: I have added the full error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the Page Information URL requesting your access token. If the access token is not present when you use the Graph API for Page Info then it will throw the same error.

You need to change the details in the current_page variable to add the access token.